# Create a new category when new action is called on separate controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Ive created 4 models: Grow, Tray, Plant, Category.  My intent is to assign a category to each model so that I can organize through categories.  When I create a new grow, a new category is created.  Then when I create a new tray, I can assign the tray to the newly created grow category.

Grow belongs_to category
Tray belongs_to category
plant belongs_to category

```
class GrowsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_grow, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


def index
  @grows = Grow.all
end


def show
end


def new
  @grow = Grow.new
end


def edit
end


def create
  @grow = Grow.new(grow_params.merge(category: Category.create(cat_params)))

  respond_to do |format|
    if @grow.save
      format.html { redirect_to @grow, notice: 'Grow was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @grow }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @grow.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# PATCH/PUT /grows/1
# PATCH/PUT /grows/1.json
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @grow.update(grow_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @grow, notice: 'Grow was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @grow }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @grow.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# DELETE /grows/1
# DELETE /grows/1.json
def destroy
  @grow.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to grows_url, notice: 'Grow was successfully destroyed.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
   end
  end

private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.

  def set_grow
    @grow = Grow.find(params[:id])
  end
  def cat_params
    params.require(:category).permit(:name)
  end
    def grow_params
      params.require(:grow).permit(:title, :notes, :category_id)
    end
  end
```

etc etc, its pretty standard setup for the views and controllers.  Im not sure how to accomplish this.  Please help steer me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def create
  @grow = Grow.new(grow_params.merge(category: Category.create(cat_params)))
end
```

Comment: Im getting this error. 

'param is missing or the value is empty: category'

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.